# What is the initial x coordinate of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In a `UITableViewController`, this function logs into the console the x coordinate of the tableview cells

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
    CATransform3D rotation;
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (45.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
    rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;


    //2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    cell.alpha = 0;

    cell.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

    //4. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    cell.alpha = 1;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"X%d= %d,Y%d=%d",(int)indexPath.row ,(int)cell.layer.position.x,(int)indexPath.row,(int)cell.layer.position.y);
}
```

it logs for the cells that are initially displayed (cell 0 to 12)

```
X0= 160,Y0=25
X1= 160,Y1=75
X2= 160,Y2=125
X3= 160,Y3=175
X4= 160,Y4=225
X5= 160,Y5=275
X6= 160,Y6=325
X7= 160,Y7=375
X8= 160,Y8=425
X9= 160,Y9=475
X10= 160,Y10=525
X11= 160,Y11=575
X12= 160,Y12=625
```

But after scrolling the tableview, it logs

```
X13= 0,Y13=675
X14= 0,Y14=725
X15= 0,Y15=775
X16= 0,Y16=825
```

and only cell 13's view is offset by 160 in the simulator

This could be fixed by adding to the previous method

```
if(cell.layer.position.x != 0){
    cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
}
```

What I am asking is why initially the x coordinate = 160 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of a layer denotes its center position, and not the top-left corner. you changed that behaviour through manipulation of the `anchorPoint` property. Insert the following line after the line that contains `anchorPoint`:

```
cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
```

Changing the `anchorPoint` also changes the `frame`. To keep the `frame` the same, you have to do the opposite movement with the `position` property.

(To get the position of the top-left corner, you would use `cell.frame.origin` instead.)

See also: [CALayer reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: But still I can't see why the 13th cell is offset by 160?

Comment: @Carpsen90: i just saw that you are changing the `anchorPoint` property to `(0, 0.5)`. This would move the view 160pt to the right. I would just remove the line that says `...anchorPoint = ...`

Comment: this line `cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);` is for the rotation to be around the leftside of the cell